# How to react with a single member of a group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a bunch of snowmen. They are all tween. When a player is captured by a specific snowman it is carried by it.

It is messy, inconvenient and time wasting to create every single sprite and set it to tween.
I have learnt to use

```
const snowman = this.physics.add.group(); snowman.create(x, y, 'key');
```

But this does not give each snowman a name. When I set the player's X and Y when it is being carried, I set it to the x and y of the snowman that hit him. If I use the code above, it will obviously no longer work. What can do instead?

[image]

Comment: Did my answer your question? If not can you share more details, that explains your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without knowing your code. I would:

- Create a variable to **mark** the snowman, that captured the player
- and when the player collides with one snowman, set variable. Like this you know which snowman.

in the `create` function:

```
function create(){

    ...
    this.mainSnowMan = undefined; // at the begining no snowman is selected
    this.physics.add.collider(player, snowman, (player, currentsnowman) => {
        ...
        this.mainSnowMan = currentsnowman; // set the snowman that collided with the player
    });
    ...
}
```

documenation to the `collider` function https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Collider.html

and here is a link so man phaser physics examples: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/physics/arcade

Comment: Thanks. So to pass the current snowman as a variable in the function. Didn’t know that. Got it.

Comment: have a problem. can't set properties of undefined

Comment: nevermind. i was being dumb. In my code i used gamestate.snowman and gameState was not a property of this.....however i forgot to delet this.mainSnowman.